# Thai visa on arrival for Indians

Tags: visas, thailand

How do I apply for a Thai visa if I'm flying in from Vietnam? I'm an Indian national. Is the process for VoA the same as when we fly in from India?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same. Go to the VoA office, just off the main Immigration channel, fill out the form, provide photo and cash, and wait.

See http://www.suvarnabhumiairport.com/en/907-suvarnabhumi-visa-on-arrival for more details.